# Unable to send Outlook Email using ASP .NET when deploying Using IIS 6.1

Tags: asp.net, outlook, iis-6

Below mentioned is the code for generating Outlook Email:

```
    Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim OutlookApplication As New Application()
    Dim email As MailItem = DirectCast(OutlookApplication.CreateItem(OlItemType.olMailItem), MailItem)
    email.Recipients.Add(txtTo.Text)
    email.Subject = "Your Subject Here"

    email.HTMLBody = "<table border=""0"" cellpadding=""0"" cellspacing=""3"" class=""MsoNormalTable"" style=""width: 100.0%; mso-cellspacing: 2.2pt; mso-yfti-tbllook: 1184; mso-padding-alt: 0in 0in 0in 0in""" & _
                         "width=""100%"">" & _
                         "<tr style=""mso-yfti-irow: 0; mso-yfti-firstrow: yes"">" & _
                             "<td style=""background: darkorange; padding: .75pt .75pt .75pt .75pt"">" & _
                                 "<p class=""MsoNormal"">" & _
                                     "<b><span style=""font-size: 13.5pt"">Email Header Here:</span></b><br/>" & _
                                     "<span style=""font-size: 10.0pt"">(This email is for information purpose.)</span><o:p></o:p>" & _
                                 "</p>" & _
                             "</td>" & _
                         "</tr>" & _
                         "<tr style=""mso-yfti-irow: 1; mso-yfti-lastrow: yes"">" & _
                             "<td style=""padding: .75pt .75pt .75pt .75pt"">" & _
                                 "<p class=""MsoNormal"">" & _
                                     "<b>1: First Point</b><br/>" & _
                        "We intend to inform you about this...<br/>" & _
                                     "<br/>" & _
                                     "<span style=""background: yellow; mso-highlight: yellow"">***Additional comments Here***</span><o:p></o:p>" & _
                                 "</p>" & _
                             "</td>" & _
                         "</tr>" & _
                     "</table>"
    email.Display()

End Sub
```

I am able to generate the email successfully when the application is running using Localhost. But when the Webpage is deployed using IIS 6.1. The page will not run.

Any suggestions for fixing this?

Answer (score 0):

Outlook cannot be used from a service (such as IIS).

You can use Exchange Web Services or raw SMTP to send a message.

Answer (score 0):

**Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.**

If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution.

You can read more about that in the [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757/en-us?wa=wsignin1.0)  article.